# how to reduce header bar height in gnome 3.18?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk3, titlebar

```
$ gnome-shell --version                                                
GNOME Shell 3.18.5

$ dpkg -s libgtk-3-0                                                       
Version: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3
```

[header bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2trFE.png)

i have try these but not working:
[Reduce title bar height in gnome 3 / gtk+ 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3)

Comment: Which version of what theme are you using? Can you provide a link for it? It looks like Adwaita but when I try the css in the link you provided the header bar shrinks. I'm guessing I either have a different version of the theme, or perhaps you didn't restart your programs after making the changes.

Comment: Sorry, i have upgraded to 18.04 and use Minwaita-Vanilla now.